# Outer and inner forloop angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, loops

I'm new to angular... What I want to do is basically a "loop in a loop" (one outer and one inner for-loop)

**html:**

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="service in services track by $index">
<td>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="sd in service.data">
        <td>How do I write here to show (line1,row1) (color1,red1) etc ?</td>
        <td>If item2 ... (line2,row2) (color2,red2)</td>
        <td>If item3 ... (line3,row3) (color3,red3)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**My controller (with the data that acts as the model):**

```
 $scope.services = [
  { index: 0, 
    name: "Getwebcolors", 
    url:"getwebcolors", 
    type: "GET", 
    description: "Hexadecimal values from {url} separated by semicolons", 
    data:[["line1","solid1"],["color1","red1"]] },
  { 
    index: 1, 
    name: "desc 2", 
    url:"", 
    type:"GET", 
    description: "X2", 
    data:[["line2","solid2"],["color2","red2"]] },
  { 
    index: 2, 
    name: "desc 3", 
    url:"", 
    type:"POST", 
    description: "X3", 
    data:[["line3","solid3"],["color3","red3"]] }
 ];
```

---

**UPDATE**

To clarify.. (I hope :-))

```
<!-- This loops through through the outer array services
and the inner array data -->
<tr ng-repeat="service in services track by $index">
<td>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="sd in service.data">
        <td>{{sd[0]}}</td><td>{{sd[1]}}</td>            
        </tr>
    </table>  
</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
```

**Above will show for the first service**

```
line 1, solid1 (first column = line1, second column = solid1)
color1, red1   (first column = color1, second column = red1)
```

and ... (same structures with columns as described in first servie above)

```
line 2, solid2
color2, red2
```

`$scope.services` is an *array of objects*. Every object has a data-attribute that is an *array of an array*. `[[` is an array and `{` is an object. That's a standard and I hope? Angular uses that to but it seems that way :-)

`$scope.services.service[index].data` contains an array and there could be unknown number of rows but each row contains a key/value pair (e.g. line1->solid1)

---

This is my first application in angular. The final purpose is to fetch information after clicked on a specific webservice

```
[button 1 = webservice 1] -> show info
[button 2 = webservice 2] -> show info
[button 3 = webservice 2] -> show info
```

---

I wanted to understand how to reference different items in the data array and to do that for-loops seemed like a good way to understand how it worked with ng-repeat. I think I did something like this from start `{{sd[0][0]}}` and `{{sd[0][1]}}` but that did not work at all (because it then takes first character of sd[0] and second character of sd[0] instead)

--
Now when I understand this I could move on with the click (I know how to bind values from $scope to an element when clicked on a button but I hade an issue with data which is an array of an array).

---

Thanks for your help! (And please tell me if I'm wrong in something I've written. That's way you learn!)

Comment: What happens if you put `({{sd[0]}, {{sd[1]}})` where you currently have `(line1,row1)`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - empty string so nothing shows there (other stuff works)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Aha now I get it.. I had to do like this:
{{sd[0]}} and in the other column {{sd[1]}} for the values to show! Thank you! ( I'm not used to the syntax {{ and }} )

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was missing a closing bracket. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be trying for something like this:

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="service in services track by $index">
<td>
    {{service.name}}
</td>
<td>
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="sd in service.data">
        <td>{{sd[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{sd[1]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `services.data` appear to have a fixed you can do this

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="sd in services">
   <td>
     ({{sd.data[0][0]}},{{sd.data[0][1]}})
    ({{sd.data[1][0]}},{{sd.data[1][1]}}) 
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No. `services.data` is an array of arrays.

Comment: `services` is an array of objects where each object has a fixed `data` that is an array of arrays and I'm looping through `services` and not `services.data` @StriplingWarrior look at it again

Comment: I see why you're interpreting it that way. I'm guessing that they meant for `data` to not have a fixed structure. There are various clues in the OP that point toward this, but the biggest one is that OP asked specifically for a "loop within a loop" and used `ng-repeat` over `services.data`.

Comment: multiple loops on the template are inefficient, they probably asked cos they don't know that. And here `"<td>How do I write here to show (line1,row1) (color1,red1) etc ?</td>"`  they mentioned how they want the data to be displayed and your answer doesn't work like that cos you're wrapping a table within a table.

Comment: By the way, I do think the elements _inside_ `data` have a fixed structure, because it appears they are key-value pairs (e.g. "color": "red"). But I could be wrong there.

Comment: No, it's an array structured like a key/value pair and that's how probably he wants to display it based on the question.

Comment: In the OP's comment on the question, OP says "I had to do like this: {{sd[0]}} and in the other column {{sd[1]}}". I interpreted that to mean they intended to have one cell for each of those two elements, but they still wanted a separate row for each element in `data`.

Comment: Well, they know best how they wish to present this data and that doesn't mean I'm wrong. So can I get my votes back please? :) :winks:

Comment: Because of your discussion in these comments I will clarify my situation with an update. I'll get back!

Comment: Sorry for me being unclear. I've updated the question now to  clarify what I actually meant :-)

Comment: @fortunee: I tried removing my down-vote after I saw your first comment here, but SO won't let me change my vote after a certain amount of time has passed unless you modify your answer. I still don't know that I'd say it's worth an up-vote, but I did see how your interpretation came from a lack of clarity in the question, and wasn't strictly incorrect.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks